# I can not register a model in my Azure ml experiment using run context

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to register a model  inside one of my azure ml  experiments. I am able to register it via `Model.register` but not via `run_context.register_model`

This are the two code sentences I use. The commented one is the one that fails

```
learn.path = Path('./outputs').absolute()
Model.register(run_context.experiment.workspace, "outputs/login_classification.pkl","login_classification", tags=metrics)
run_context.register_model("login_classification", "outputs/login_classification.pkl", tags=metrics)
```

I received the next error:

```
Message: Could not locate the provided model_path outputs/login_classification.pkl
```

But model is stored in this path:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing `run_context.register_model()` implement `run_context = Run.get_context()`

I was able to fix the problem by explicitly uploading the model into the run history record before trying for registering the model.

```
run.upload_file("output/model.pickle", "output/model.pickle")
```

Check the documentation for [Message: Could not locate the provided model_path outputs/login_classification.pkl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.exceptions.modelpathnotfoundexception?view=azure-ml-py)

To check about [Run Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py#upload-file-name--path-or-stream-)